# Wildfly 10 context root using jboss-web.xml file doesn't work

Tags: gradle, wildfly

I've created a war (`authz-demo-HEAD-400f6db-dirty.war`) and I've deployed it on a Wildfly 10 instance.

I've set a `jboss-web.xml` file in WEB-INF folder in order to set the application context root.

Even thought I've set on `jboss-web.xml` I need a `living_authz` context root, Wildfly keep using `authz-demo-HEAD-400f6db-dirty` as context root.

**EDITED**

I've realized `jboss-web.xml` is in `authz-demo-HEAD-400f6db-dirty.war\WEB-INF\classes\WEB-INF`...

The `beans.xml` is also in `authz-demo-HEAD-400f6db-dirty.war\WEB-INF\classes\WEB-INF` with context:

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

</beans>
```

I'm using this gradle script:

```
task createDemoWar(type: War, dependsOn: classes) {
    archiveName "webapi-demo-${versioning.info.display}.war"
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/dist")
    webInf {
        from('scopes') {
            include 'demo.persistence.xml'
            rename('demo.persistence.xml', 'persistence.xml')
            into('classes/META-INF/')
        }
        from('scopes') {
            include 'configuration.demo.properties'
            rename('configuration.demo.properties', 'scope.properties')
            into('classes/')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `jboss-web.xml`? If it's in the `authz-demo-HEAD-400f6db-dirty.war/WEB-INF` directory it should definitely be getting read.

Comment: Do you have also empty beans.xml?

Comment: Dears, I've just edited the post answering you...